# Gmail app on Android can't send messages since months

Tags: android, gmail, firmware

I've got the issue that the Gmail app on Android (OnePlus One device) is unable to send messages (it stays in Outbox instead of Sent). Once in the past, I've solved this by clearing the Gmail app cache, another time by disabling and enabling Google account sync for Gmail (which is parallel to Contacts, Photos, etc). Switching Wi-Fi/mobile transmission, and restarting the phone doesn't help. The WiFi is fiber 1Gbit downlink, 300Mbit uplink, and no issues with sending the same Gmail mail via IMAP.

Inspecting the logcat gets me to the below lines

```
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.DiskWriteViolation
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1614)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1228)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:733)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:325)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:300)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:738)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:648)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.AbstractSyncableContentProvider.delete(AbstractSyncableContentProvider.java:354)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentProvider.delete(ContentProvider.java:1832)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:443)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:215)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1326)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1268)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode: # via Binder call with stack:
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:2496)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:2985)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:139)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:629)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:2377)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:2337)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at uze.ck(PG:21)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at qta.a(PG:454)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at axuv.c(PG:3)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at axux.run(PG:42)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at aalz.run(PG:3)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at yaw.run(PG:47)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
10-25 10:25:02.367 11495 11627 D StrictMode:    at aamc.run(PG:51)
10-25 10:25:02.370  6945  6967 W SyncableContentProvider: Failed to find Google signatures. Defaulting to allow for: com.google.android.gm
```

I'm wondering if Google code is that low quality that it does I/O in a front thread via some dynamic code loading, or if they missed some signature? Or it's some override by OnePlus/malicious software?
Here is the partial output of `adb shell pm dump com.google.android.gm`:

```
Domain verification status:
  com.google.android.gm:
    ID: 9f2c825e-7198-4a77-b08e-deee27c981f2
    Signatures: [7C:E8:3C:1B:71:F3:D5:72:FE:D0:4C:8D:40:C5:CB:10:FF:75:E6:D8:7D:9D:F6:FB:D5:3F:04:68:C2:90:50:53]
    Domain verification state:
      gmail.app.goo.gl: verified
      dynamite-autopush.sandbox.google.com: verified
      tel.meet: verified
      d.meet: verified
      chat.google.com: verified
      t.meet: verified
      dynamite-preprod.sandbox.google.com: verified
      enterprise.google.com: verified
      stream.meet.google.com: verified
      client-side-encryption.google.com: verified
      dial.meet: verified
      meet.google.com: verified
      krahsc.google.com: verified
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Disabled:
          gmail.app.goo.gl
          dynamite-autopush.sandbox.google.com
          tel.meet
          d.meet
          chat.google.com
          t.meet
          dynamite-preprod.sandbox.google.com
          enterprise.google.com
          stream.meet.google.com
          client-side-encryption.google.com
          dial.meet
          meet.google.com
          krahsc.google.com
```

and what's seems suspicious to me:

```
Packages:
  Package [com.google.android.gm] (49d7b03):
    userId=10148
    pkg=Package{23200e1 com.google.android.gm}
    codePath=/data/app/~~XlVPy9DOYBeeXI0dHWytXQ==/com.google.android.gm-PQRNAYJIaYO6Hcjwh3KBgA==
    resourcePath=/data/app/~~XlVPy9DOYBeeXI0dHWytXQ==/com.google.android.gm-PQRNAYJIaYO6Hcjwh3KBgA==
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/~~XlVPy9DOYBeeXI0dHWytXQ==/com.google.android.gm-PQRNAYJIaYO6Hcjwh3KBgA==/lib
    extractNativeLibs=false
    primaryCpuAbi=arm64-v8a
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    cpuAbiOverride=null
    versionCode=64193435 minSdk=23 targetSdk=34
    minExtensionVersions=[]
    versionName=2023.10.08.572379699.Release
    usesNonSdkApi=false
    splits=[base, config.arm64_v8a, config.pl, config.xxhdpi]
    apkSigningVersion=3
[...]
Hidden system packages:
  Package [com.google.android.gm] (25958b9):
    userId=10148
    pkg=Package{12954fe com.google.android.gm}
    codePath=/product/app/Gmail2
    resourcePath=/product/app/Gmail2
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/product/app/Gmail2/lib
    extractNativeLibs=false
    primaryCpuAbi=arm64-v8a
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    cpuAbiOverride=null
    versionCode=63768557 minSdk=23 targetSdk=33
    minExtensionVersions=[]
    versionName=2023.03.05.518353126.Release
    usesNonSdkApi=false
    splits=[base]
    apkSigningVersion=0
    flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP KILL_AFTER_RESTORE RESTORE_ANY_VERSION LARGE_HEAP ]
    privateFlags=[ PRIVATE_FLAG_ACTIVITIES_RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE ALLOW_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_CAPTURE PRIVATE_FLAG_REQUEST_LEGACY_EXTERNAL_STORAGE HAS_DOMAIN_URLS PARTIALLY_DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE PRODUCT PRIVATE_FLAG_ALLOW>
    forceQueryable=false
    queriesPackages=[com.google.android.apps.mobileutilities, com.android.settings, com.google.android.apps.meetings, com.google.android.apps.tasks, com.google.android.calendar, com.google.android.youtube, com.>
    queriesIntents=[Intent { act=com.android.setupwizard.action.PARTNER_CUSTOMIZATION }, Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE }, Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market:/... }, Intent { ac>
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gm
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    usesOptionalLibraries:
      org.apache.http.legacy
      androidx.window.extensions
      androidx.window.sidecar
    usesOptionalNativeLibraries:
      libOpenCL.so
      libOpenCL-car.so
      libOpenCL-pixel.so
      libedgetpu_util.so
      libedgetpu_client.google.so
```

Is this not signed part of some override by OnePlus? (the firmware is stock, non-rooted, OEM unlocked for future root possibility)

Comment: I don't think this is a very good fit for this site. It's not off topic, but it's probably not what we as a collective knows most about. I would perhaps suggest [trying Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/). They may have more insight in how this *should* look.